# Two streams for inter-related models?

Tags: getstream-io

If we have users and posts - and I can follow a user (and see all their posts), or follow a particular post (and see all it's edits/updates), would each post be pushed to two seperate streams, one for the user and another for the post?

---

My concern is that if a user follows an idea, and also the user feed, their aggregated activity-feed could show multiple instances of the same idea, one from each feed.

Answer (score 1):

Every unique activity will only appear at most once in a feed. To make an activity have the exact same internal ID, you might try using the `to` field. This add an activity into different feed groups with the same activity UUID.

If this is not possible, at least make an activity unique, by both entering the same `time` and `foreign_id` values. This will make an activity unique as well.

Cheers!